# Is autocommit supposed to allow/disallow rollback in MySql

Tags: mysql, transactions

```
SET autocommit = 0;
start transaction;
update ... where ID=29;
rollback;
```

Whether autocommit is 1 or 0 does not seem to affect the rollback? Does autocommit ontrol whether update is committed immediately or not? What does autocommit supposed to affect?

Comment: are you encountering an actual problem?  is there something in particular that isn't doing what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

From documentation  [autocommit, Commit, and Rollback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html):

> If autocommit mode is enabled, **each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own**

It means that after DML statement ends(without error), it is committed(unless it is wrapped with explicit transaction).

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have autocommit enabled, that doesn't stop you from starting a transaction. When you explicitly start a transaction, this supercedes autocommit for the duration of the transaction. Once you commit (or rollback), autocommit resumes at its previous value.

So if you explicitly start a transaction, you can rollback, even if normally you have autocommit enabled.